# PHP Regex jump onto new line

Tags: regex

I have a massive string containing steps for a recipe.
I am trying to have the steps display when they are a new number.

So for example, at the moment they look like

```
1. Mix all dry ingredients together. 2. Mix all wet ingredients together. 3. Combine all ingredients.
```

I would like it to display like:

```
1. Mix all dry ingredients together. 
2. Mix all wet ingredients together. 
3. Combine all ingredients.
```

My plan is to have the string jump onto a new line when it matches ". NUMBER. " The regex is `\.\s[0-9]{1,}\.\s`

Can anyone tell me how this would be done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match using this regex:

```
/\h+(?=\d+\.\h+)/
```

and replace with `\n`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nqtdxb/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespace
- `(?=\d+\.\h+)`: Lookahead to assert presence of 1+ digits followed by a dot followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace

Comment: sorry I am figuring out how to incorporate this into the PHP code but it does seem like the right thing im looking for thank you

Comment: Demo link I provided also has relevant PHP code: https://regex101.com/r/Nqtdxb/1/codegen?language=php